# Create table with conditions & from several source

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a table with column from two other tables.
I also need to have condition on several of the column (typically testing if the value of the row is not null).
I have tried several ways, but I only managed to add as much column as I want from one other table, without any conditions testing.

here basically what I'd like to make :

```
CREATE TABLE target_table
AS(        
SELECT column1 FROM source_table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT column2, column3 FROM source_table1
UNION
SELECT column1 FROM source_table2
)
```

with this query I get the : "query block has incorrect number of result columns" error.

I have tried also this :

```
CREATE TABLE target_table
AS(        
SELECT column1 FROM source_table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT column2 FROM source_table1
)
```

It "works" as there are no errors, but none of the column2 rows are in my target_table.
This is probably trivial but I have been unable to find any answer of these kind of table creation with condition and several column origin..

Comment: . . .This question is vague.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of column should be same for union operator
and data type also have to be same

```
CREATE TABLE target_table
AS select * from    
 (        
SELECT column1, ' ' as column3 FROM source_table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT column2, column3 FROM source_table1
UNION
SELECT column1, '' FROM source_table2
) t
```

So in your query number of column was not same

Comment: You have misunderstood the problem and your solution does not work.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. When I try your solution, even with two columns from the same target_table, I still have the same error returned

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin this solution create a table with column1 rows (not null) and another column "col3" with a lot of "nulls" and a few data from column2. My purpose would be to create a table with the 2 or more columns from source_table, with a few simple not null tests.

Comment: @ThZ if you want to avoid null then put their blank string if data type is varchar i edited

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin thanks again for your help. I have found another way to select the non-null column as I wanted `SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM source_table WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL` , but I think `UNION` might not be the right command for my problem..

Comment: @ThZ as you have not shared source data so i could not help about that i just noticed you about your current query problem btw if it helps you may accept this as a correct answer for current problem thanks

Comment: I upvoted because I think this answers the question as asked.  If it is not the intended question, the right approach is for the OP to ask *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You just need to add an empty column where you want to get only one. Do not forget to cast the column into data type. Bellow example is for string type column. If you want to get integer column from source_table2 then place this select statement at above of all.

```
CREATE TABLE target_table
AS(        
SELECT column1 , '' FROM source_table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT column2, column3 FROM source_table2
UNION
SELECT column1 , '' FROM source_table3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You just need to add an empty column where you want to get only one. Do not forget to cast the column into data type. Bellow example is for string type column.

```
CREATE TABLE target_table
AS(        
SELECT column1 , '' FROM source_table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT column2, column3 FROM source_table2
UNION
SELECT column1 , '' FROM source_table3
)
```

If you want to get integer column from source_table2 then place this select statement at above of all.

```
CREATE TABLE target_table
    AS(    
 SELECT column2, column3 FROM source_table2    
    UNION
    SELECT column1 , null FROM source_table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL


    UNION
    SELECT column1 , null FROM source_table3
    )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. there are only varchar() columns on these tables. I have an error on the select with the first code you proposed : sql command not properly ended. is this related to the format of the column?

Comment: @ThZ you can check my answer

Comment: i have forgot to place the allias of empty column. you can check my 2nd solution